# Batch checking the last character

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem in a folder which contains sql files. 
I want to check that the last line of each file contain only one slash '/' (without any spaces after that) and if there is issue to write in the output that an error is raised
ie     1.sql   error
       5.sql   error

Is there any easy way to do it with a batch file ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: yes, it is faily easy.

Comment: in what language?  bash? windows.bat?

Comment: @nabin-info, hover your mouse over the `batch-file` tag.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far! Otherwise this is a write-code-for-me post which is off-topic here. Consult the following help topic: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it :

```
@echo off&cls

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*.sql) do (echo Treating =^> %%a
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('type "%%a"') do (
        set "$Line=%%b"
    )
    echo   - Last Char =^> [!$Line:~-1!]
    if not "!$Line:~-1!"=="/" (
        echo   - Result =^> error %%~nxa
        ) else (
        echo   - Result =^> OK %%~nxa
        )
    echo.^****
)
```